# Adding a 3-D Ribbon Effect on Font in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, 3d, gradient

I am trying to create a 3D ribbon effect on my typed text (I used the font called Sacramento) and I am following this tutorial: http://design.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-silky-ribbon-text-effect--vector-3771

I thought I was following the tutorial exactly, but I am getting hung up at step 3 and 4. I can't seem to fill the divided shapes with a gradient that stops and starts where I divided the path. Instead the gradient goes all the way across the font until the second "L" in Cinderella. Any guidance would be appreciated!

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You havn't divided the shapes properly.

After dividing the shapes, they should be completely separate shapes which you can separate, like number 3 on this image from the tutorial:

[image]

If you have followed step 3 and created all the separating paths where you want them, the paths may not be completely covering the shape. What i normally do, which they don't in the tutorial is make sure the separating path extends over the edge of the shape.

So instead of this:

[image]

I would do this:

[image]